# Importing node_modules into Laravel via Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, npm, openlayers, openlayers-5

I'm trying to use OpenLayers (v5.3.0) in a Laravel 5.7 project, but am having a lot of trouble importing ol from node_modules.

I installed ol as follows (based on https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol):

```
npm install ol
```

I then updated my resources\js\app.js, which now contains only the following:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('ol');
```

**EDIT:** I've also tried the following in resources\js\app.js, without success:

```
require('./bootstrap');
const ol = require('ol');
```

My webpack.mix.js contains the following:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js', )
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I also have the following relevant lines in a file called map.blade.php, which is where I want to display the OpenLayers map:

```
<script src="{!! mix('js/app.js') !!}"></script>
...
<div id='map' style='z-index: 1; width: 100%; height:calc(100% - 56px);'>
    <script>
        import Map from 'ol/Map';
        import View from 'ol/View';
        import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
        import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';

        new Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new XYZ({
                        url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                    })
                })
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2
            })
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

I have also run `npm run dev`.

When testing in Chrome, I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" referring to the following line in map.blade.php:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
```

**EDIT:** I've also run the following to make sure all dependencies are installed:

```
npm install --save-dev parcel-bundler
```

I didn't get any errors when running the above, but the same error in Chrome is still there.

**EDIT:** I've also tried shifting the javascript out of my map.blade.php into a new file (mapscript.js), and then importing that in map.blade.php (after the 'map' div) as follows:

```
<script src="{!! asset('js/mapscript.js') !!}" type="module"></script>
```

But then I get the following error instead:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "ol/Map". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Following that, I tried moving the following line out of app.js and into mapscript.js:

```
require('ol');
```

And also tried the same with:

```
const ol = require('ol');
```

But the same Uncaught TypeError persists in both cases.

I've tried the solutions given to a lot of similar questions in Stack Overflow and elsewhere, and I've also tried using ol outside of npm, but I haven't found anything that resolves the issue for me. I believe using npm and Mix is the best way to build OpenLayers into my project, but I can't work out why it's not working. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I got the same issue ..Did u solved this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error I have OpenLayers 6.1 working with Laravel 6.2 using Mix, Webpack, and ES6 module imports. The trick is to write all your javascript in a separate file and bundle it up into app.js.

Install openlayers into your Laravel project using npm:

```
npm install ol
```

Create a new file in your Laravel project at `resources/js/myMap.js` (alongside `bootstrap.js` and `app.js`) and put your OpenLayers javascript code into it.

Lets use a short code example copied from the official docs at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

const map = new Map({
    target: 'osm_map',
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 0
    })
});
```

We need to export this as a literal object to make it available to other code, so insert the five extra lines as shown below.

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

var my_map = {                       // <-- add this line to declare the object
    display: function () {           // <-- add this line to declare a method 

        const map = new Map({
            target: 'osm_map',
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 0
            })
        });

    }                                // <-- close the method
};                                   // <-- close the object
export default my_map;               // <-- and export the object
```

Add these two lines to the end of `bootstrap.js` so that it incorporates our code, and attach our object my_map to the global window object so we can reference it from the page.

```
import my_map from './myMap.js';
window.my_map = my_map;
```

Now bundle it all up by executing `npm run dev`. Note that we are using Laravel's default webpack and mix configurations - we haven't needed to edit `webpack.mix.js` at all. 
`npm run dev` copies the code in our `myMap.js` file into `app.js`. We need to run this each time we edit `myMap.js`. ( `npm run watch` can be used to automate this step ).

To get the map displayed in a blade template we need to have a div id matching the OpenLayers Map target, `osm_map` in our example code above. Here's a minimal blade.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        #osm_map {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <div id="osm_map"></div>
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.my_map.display();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note:

1. The div id="osm_map" matches the openlayers target.
2. The OpenLayers CSS was also bundled and is referenced here. This styles the OpenLayers controls.
3. The map is displayed when we call our my_map.display() method.

This successfully displays an interactive OpenLayers map inside a Laravel blade template.

Comment: This is fantastic. Got the basic example working successfully! Can't thank you enough. FYI, I just had to remove the semicolon at the end of the 'close the method' line in myMap.js.

Answer (score 1):

Install `ol` package :

```
npm install ol
```

Inside your resources directory in js folder(where bootstrap.js and app.js exists) create a file name map.js

```
resources/js/map.js
```

Write your Openlayer code in map.js(example code):

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map,View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

const map = new Map({
target: 'map',
layers: [
    new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
    })
],
view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
             })
});
```

Now, goto `webpack.mix.js`, it is usually at the end.

Add `.js('resources/js/map.js', 'public/js')` at end of the file

`webpack.mix.js` will look like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.js('resources/js/map.js', 'public/js');
```

Now, `npm run dev` in terminal

Your `*.blade.php` code should be as following example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Using Webpack with OpenLayers</title>
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: fixed;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/map.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Importing node modules from public folder directly is not allowed. Here, we import module within the project and use it with the help of `webpack` in the public folder.

For production: `npm run production` in terminal